# How to Send Email using CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to send an email to a user using CasperJS.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can call your favorite commandline e-mail tool or automate your favorite e-mail website. There are too many possible answers to your question. Try something yourself and come back when you have a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using [SpookyJS](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS), which allows you to drive [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) from [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), then you can use the [Gmail API for Node.js](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) to send email.

This will probably be one of your most dependable methods for accomplishing this task.

If it is not possible to use SpookyJS, you can use the underlying [PhantomJS Child Process Module](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/) which is built underneath CasperJS.

> The child_process module allows you to invoke subprocesses and communicate with them via stdin / stdout / stderr. This is useful for tasks such as printing, sending mail, or invoking scripts or programs written in another language (not Javascript).

This will allow you to access the command line on your server via CasperJS to run the email program of your choice.

Here's an example snippet of CasperJS interacting with the command line to execute a Bash program that sends out an email:

```
var process = require('child_process');

process.execFile('/bin/bash', ['send-email.sh', args1, args2, args3], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  this.log('execFileSTDOUT:', JSON.stringify(stdout), 'debug');
  this.log('execFileSTDERR:', JSON.stringify(stderr), 'debug');
});
```